# How do I have a getter that returns a pointer of another object?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, getter

I found online the following to get an object of another class:

```
Class A{
.........
 B b;
.........
const B& getB()const{
return b;
}

};
```

And the following to get a pointer to an object of another class:

```
Class A{
.........
B* b;
void setB(B *x) { b=x; }
B *getB() const { return b; }
.........


};
```

I have a following situation:

```
 Class A{
.........
 B** b;
 A(int i){ b = new B*[i] ;}
.........
};
```

I want to return the B* from A.So that `new a(4)->getB()` will return `b[4]`. Do I do the following:

```
    Class A{
    .........
     B** b;
     A(int i){ b = new B*[i] ;}
    .........
    const B&* getB() const{ return b; }
   ........
    };
```

My intention is to return an object from an array of object pointers which I initialized inside the constructor of another class.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like `const B&* getB()` before.

Comment: "So that new a(4).getB() will return b[4]" sorry but I cannot make any sense out of this

Comment: I am new to C++ btw so I'm not sure either.

Comment: then please let us know what you actually want to do instead of some weird way how you are trying to solve it

Comment: I explicitly mentioned what I want to do.I want to return an object from an array of object pointers of another class.

Comment: then what about `B* getB(int index) {return b[index]);` ? If you want to return one pointer from the array you have to pick one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return a reference to the pointer-to-const-B that has been previously stored as the fifth element of the array.

```
const B*& getB() const{ return b[4]; }
```

Note that your usage. `new a(4)->getB()` will invoke undefined behavior since there are only four elements in the array.

Comment: Excellent! So it is valid and I just figured out myself!

Comment: Note the difference between your code and mine. Yours `const B&* getB()..`. Mine: `const B*& getB()...`.

Comment: Btw the use of & is still confusing to me.Is it related to B or getB()? I mean do you do `B&  getB()`or  `B  &getB()?`

Comment: @Arnob `B*&` is a reference (`&`) to a pointer (`*`) to an `B` instance

Answer (score 1):

```
const B** getB() const{ return b; }
```

This is what you want?

Instead of fighting with raw pointers maybe consider using some container (std::vector?) or smart pointers. If no, please provide some better information about you problem.

EDIT

> I want to return an object from an array of object pointers of another class

Ok so

```
const B* getB(size_t index) const{ return b[index]; }
```